# import/embed xml ocr/text info from one pdf to a different pdf

Tags: pdf, pdf-generation

I am trying to optimize quality/filesize of a image-scanned pdf while retaining ocr quality.

I could try and downsample after ocr of the high quality pdf document but the tools I'm using (acrobat primarily) do not create small file sizes as compared to using photoshop and exporting a lower dpi/optimized pages and using these pages to create a pdf.

A better solution,  if possible would be to take a image-pdf document (800M for the current case) that has been ocred and apply the ocr layer to a lower-rez downsampled document.

I can successfully extract the OCR info with coordinates as xml with pdfminer, but I would like to take this and apply it the same file that has been downsampled using photoshop.  I thought I read this was possible with pdftk but I can no longer find this information.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

jack

Answer (score 0):

Can you describe what's the current way your create PDFs?

With IText it's possible to [set the compression level](http://api.itextpdf.com/itext/com/itextpdf/text/Image.html#setCompressionLevel%28int%29) of images added.

May be useful